# wxPython -- How to Bind all area inside a staticbox?

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

I have a staticbox and a staticboxsizer linked to it with 3 different static texts inside.  How do I bind the entire box so that any place inside the area covered by the static box is a click event to something?  Said in another way, how can I turn a static box into a button (I don't want a button, though).

I've tried binding the static box itself but that only captures clicks on the outline of the box or the label.  I've considered trying to bind the staticboxsizer, too, but I can't give a staticboxsizer an ID which is necessary to figure out which box the click originated.  I toyed with binding everything, the box, sizer, and text, but it seems there should be a more elegant way.  Binding the static texts is a possibility, but it misses some of the area and I would have to bind 3 different things.

EDIT: I know how to bind and which event to bind, my question is regarding how to get the area so I can bind it.

Thanks.

Comment: you cannot bind to a staticboxsizer... make a panel ... and put the binding on the panel

Comment: Well, then that's not an option even if I could have assigned it an ID.  Thanks for the info.  Any idea how to do the above?

Comment: make a wx.Panel ... add your  elements .. bind EVT_LEFT_DOWN (I think thats the event ...)

Comment: Yes, that's the event.  I thought of that but I was trying to keep the label functionality of the static box.  I suppose I could fill the static box with a panel and put things inside and then bind the panel?  I'll give it a go.

Comment: sure ... or just add the StaticBox to the panel ... either way ... but you can only bind to widgets ... sizers are not widgets